# Authenticating with User instead of Apps for Webhooks

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad, webhooks

I cloned the example repo for creating webhooks on SharePoint-Online Libraries (found here:https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebHooks.Nodejs/), but want to execute my event *as the user*, because i'd like to check-in listitems, the user edited.

Is there any way, i can do that by authenticating the app in the azure active directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot impersonate a user with webhooks. You can use stored credentials or app-only context, that's about it.